# How can I best restore ancient text-file email backups into a more modern email format?

Tags: email, backup, thunderbird

Like many of us, I have decades of email now that's sprinkled through my backups, often from when I would move to a new computer or migrate from one OS to another. I now have a bunch of ancient email backups that are in plain text, apparently just one giant huge file with each email right after the other, no way to use it in an email program. I can read them sequentially by using Emacs but it's a 500MB file and to "use" it I have to just search through the whole file. Is there any way to import this into Thunderbird, my current email program?

Part of the complexity here is that I am not sure what client I was using at the time. It may have been Kmail, but I can't remember. If it helps, the format is like this in my presumed backup:

```
myemail@my.email.address.edu
```

And then some matching files are like

```
.myemail@my.email.address.edu.ids
```

Do I have any way of importing these into some modern, usable form, such as Thunderbird (my current client) or perhaps some other email-friendly program?

I currently use Lubuntu 20.04LTS, with Thunderbird as my email client.  Ideally, I'd end up with these emails in some format that Thunderbird can import and thus pull them back into my system. But I'd accept an offline way to read them as emails as well.

Comment: It sounds like your mail is stored in "mailbox" format. There are tools to split it into individual files (ie Maildir format) and I expect thats what you want.  Look at mb2md ( http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/mb2md.1.html )  This is a comment as I dont know how firefox handles its mail  but if your mail server uses dovecot you can likely just bang these into an appropriate directory with correct perms and dovecot will make them available over imap to the client.

Comment: Look [here at this other SuperUser thread](https://superuser.com/q/1169371/167207); it seems like that question is about the opposite of what you are attempting to do, but there are lots of answers and comments that might be helpful in some way.

Answer (score 0):

### `mailbox` file to maildir conversion

You may `formail` to execute "per email" command with email feed to stdin of the command
(e.g. `formail -s procmail -m procmail.rcfile < mailbox_file`)
On Debian-Linux formail is provided by procmail package.

There are other ways but for "once per **LONG** time" it is the simplest IMHO.

### HUGE maildir indexing/searching

You may use `mu4e` (Mail Utils For Emacs) with emacs for maildir indexing and searching.
`mu4e` is available as Debian-Linux package.